# Iphone app using Phonegap and the OS and IDE I can use

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have a requirement from client to develop an iPhone application. As I am a dot net developer I thought it will be bit challenging for me. So I thought of developing it using phone gap. So before suggesting something to the client I need to make sure of certain points.

**Do I really need a mac machine to develop this?**

Since I am using only html5, css and js, can I develop it in Visual studio/Eclipse? I have already tried some samples in both these IDE. And once the app is ready I have read about using **PhoneGap Build** I can make it ready to use in iPhone...

But from the following link, what I understood is I need an apple computer, mac os and Xocde to develop it even though it is not a native mobile app.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/phonegap-development/

Please guide me with some insights before talking to the client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> PhoneGap Build is a cloud-based service built on top of the PhoneGap
>   framework. It allows you to easily build those same mobile apps in the
>   cloud. To get your application build just what you need is to simply
>   upload your web assets - a ZIP file of HTML, CSS and JavaScript, to
>   PhoneGap Build, after some time you’ll receive the download URLs for
>   all mobile platforms.

I read it from [here](https://build.phonegap.com/faq) , they also mentioned about installing SDKs

> you might want to install some of the SDK emulators if you don’t own a
>   particular device that you want to test a build for.

Here in this [link](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/ios-builds) they have put a note

> Since PhoneGap Build uses Apple's standard development process to
>   build applications, you will need to sign up for their developer
>   program to build iOS applications on PhoneGap Build. You will also
>   need a Mac to configure your certificate and provisioning profile.

Consider using a Mac Virtual machine.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply.."you might want to install some of the SDK emulators if you don’t own a particular device that you want to test a build for." -- is it possible without mac virtual machine?

Comment: @Dev no its not possible to do without a Mac

Answer (score 1):

You mainly need a mac to create key value chain pairs to sign your app and test it on a device. You can just get a Mac VM to do this is my recommendation. You can then use the phonegap build service to compile your www folder for iOS

Here is a good demo for multiple index files to have one solution base
http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/07/13/mcrooster-a-phonegap-application-with-a-single-codebase/

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply.. so is it okay if I develop it in Visual studio(in windows machine) and test it in  mac os with its emulator?

Comment: I think thats not possible..rt since we have separate file for each platform supported by PhoneGap..

Comment: one more doubt if at all I dont need to access any device feature in my app is it necessary to use Phonegap? I mean can i create mobile app using html5,css and js and any of teh mobile framework like JqueryMobile/SenchaTouch or KendoUIMobile?

Comment: it is possible, just include both iOS and android cordova js libray in your www folder. Some people achieve this by having multiple index.html files, one for each platform

Comment: I've added a link to my answer

Comment: and yes you can create an app with phonegap + JqueryMobile/SenchaTouch or KendoUIMobile

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do a bit more research before jumping into bed with PhoneGap for the sake of not being an Objective-C developer. PhoneGap has its limitations, and my experience of it compared with native app development is pretty poor.

Comment: Yes, from my experience also phonegap has limitations for eg uploading multiple image type from camera. It will not support support both jpeg and png together. But I liked the product because it is pretty much easy  to develop mobile application using phonegap.